# Vue draggable, only drag inside container

Tags: javascript, vue.js, sortablejs, vuedraggable

I know that VueDraggable is based on SortableJs, and whatever options we hav available in this, is also in the Vue version.
My current problem is that I want to prevent that the item you are dragging, can be dragged outside the parent container?

So what I want, is basically only allow it to be dragged inside the parent container - and if dragged outside, it should overflow like so: https://jmp.sh/K8bAP8c

Is this even possible to do with VueDraggable/SortableJS? It seems like whatever you are dragging placed "on top" on the screen, which is why it's not possible to do an overflow hidden to keep it "inside" the parent container?

I havent found any way to do it, but maybe im lucky and someone knows how?